# How to download a file and and stay in current page in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want that when user clicked on Download button, i check his status and if it is valid, a video file start to download, and user stay in current page. 
video file are placed in another host.
to do this after checking user validity i redirect user to video file address and do not know how to keep him in current page. i have done this :

```
public ActionResult Download(string url)
{
    return Redirect(url);
}
```

how can i do this ?

Comment: you can use my downloader (https://github.com/rndme/download) as an ajax callback, so you would feed the url to a simple ajax call and that page would be saved with the file name specified, without reloading the page.

Comment: Please note that the [tag:model-view-controller] tag is intended for questions about the *pattern*. Since your question is about the ASP.NET implementation, use the [tag:asp.net-mvc] tag (which I've added here for you) and/or one of the version-specific variations.

Answer (score 0):

If the video file is in another address, not in the MVC application. Just have them go to that link directly in JavaScript.

One way to do that is to throw in an `iframe`.

```
$('body').append('<iframe src="url" />');
```

This will trigger a download in the same page.

Comment: that would only trigger a download for some file types, not documents, images, text, mp4 videos, etc...

Answer (score 0):

To do so in MVC you have to make a link to an action that looks something like this:

```
public ActionResult GetFile()
{
    File(\*several overloads here*\);
}
```

and so once the user clicks the link it will prompted by the browser to download the file

Comment: first i had done this, but it this will download file from destination host to source host and then download it. returning a file in action will download it from itself server not the other one. @Luise